# YouTube new video notification Android

Tags: android

I everyone I’m currently in the process of creating an Android application for my YouTube channel. I was wondering if anyone knew if there was any way to check for a new video uploads so I could use it to trigger a notification within my application.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the Youtube API. Although im not sure how well the GData-API for YouTube is supported on Android (or if it supports checking for videos at all, never used it myself).
Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/overview.html) and see if you can find something.

Or you could load and parse the RSS-Feed at
http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/YOURCHANNELNAME/videos.rss.
Since RSS is XML based, that is certainly possible.